# WiX: is it possible to use the variable name as a part of other variable name?

Tags: wix

I wrote this in my WiX project file (I simplified my examples):

```
<?define info = R172 ?>
<?define var1="$(var.info.TargetPath)" ?>
<?define var2="$(var.info.TargetDir)" ?>
```

I would like the `info` will be expanded by preprocessor into such variant:

```
<?define var1="$(var.R172.TargetPath)" ?>
<?define var2="$(var.R172.TargetDir)" ?>
```

But I get the error:

> Undefined preprocessor variable `$(var.info.TargetPath)`.

This variant doesn't work too:

```
<?define var1="$(var.$(var.info).TargetPath)" ?>
<?define var2="$(var.$(var.info).TargetDir)" ?>
```

Also I have tried `foreach` using:

```
<?foreach info in R172?>
<?define var1="$(var.info.TargetPath)" ?>
<?define var2="$(var.info.TargetDir)" ?>
<?endforeach?>
```

But I get the same problem.

Can I do the similar substitution somehow?

**UPD**

I.e. I want to use it for working with referenced projects through the `foreach`:

```
<!-- The list of the names of referensed projects -->
<?define ACAD_VERSIONS=R172;R182;R190?>

<?foreach ACAD in ACAD_VERSIONS?>
  <Feature Id="Feature.$(var.ACAD)" Title="$(var.ACAD)" Level="1">
    <Component Id="cmp$(var.ACAD)" Guid="*" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
      <File Id="extension.$(var.ACAD).dll" Source="$(var.$(var.ACAD).TargetPath)"  KeyPath="yes"/>
    </Component>
  </Feature>
<?endforeach?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the current version of WIX (3.10.2) doesn't appear to support what you are requesting.

Looking at the WIX source code, specifically the file `src\tools\wix\PreProcessorCore.cs` from WIX310-Debug.zip downloadable from [here](https://wix.codeplex.com/releases/view/619491), it doesn't look like WIX supports recursive name substitution.  So you can't do `$(var.$(var.something))`.  Take a look at the function `PreprocessString(...)` to confirm this for yourself.

You might be able to do something with `<?undef ...?>`.  For example:

```
<?define var1="$(var.item1)" ?>
<?include CommonFeature.wxs ?>
.
<?undef var1 ?>
<?define var1="$(var.item2)" ?>
<?include CommonFeature.wxs ?>
```

See the related WIXToolset issue: [Nested preprocessor variables](https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/4007).

Comment: But the problem what I want to use `var1` like the link to the referenced projects for handling of their content through the `foreach` loop. I added **UPD** section in my sample for clarity.

Comment: Thank you. I.e. this feature was added into WiX 4 version. Did I understand your correctly?

Comment: Unfortunately this feature isn't in WiX version 4 either.  The current status of [Nested preprocessor variables](https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/4007) shows it as open and planned for WiX version 4.